# Play! Limit access to specific routes (like Limit in Apache)

Tags: apache, playframework, routes

I'm looking for any method to filter the access to /login and /register (and potentially, any custom url or entry in routes), to prevent users outside the lan (or an ip range) access thouse pages.

Something like in Apache is simply done by:

```
 <Limit POST PUT DELETE>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from ip list or dns
 </Limit>
```

Play server is running on linux (Ubuntu Server 10.04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Do it [using custom annotation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaActionsComposition#Defining-custom-action-annotations) so you can add your own filtering mechanics.
2. Use... Apache (or maybe some lighter HTTP server) as reverse proxy for your app (my favourite for this issue) so you can control access there by its rules. [Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/HTTPServer)

Comment: I read about your reverse proxy suggestion, and I think that would fit.
After installing apache2 (on my ubuntu 14.04.2 server) and loading proxy module, I realized that I needed further configuration and modules since I'm running Play 2.3.8 server on https, for production purposes. What do you think would be the best approach here? I think probably lettting apache2 to handle https, and configuring a reverse proxy to address http on Play server.

Comment: Yes, reverse proxy ___was___ only way to work with https in early 2.x versions, anyway it was fixed later (TBH, I don't remember in which version exactly) anyway you still can use reverse server to handle SSL connections

Answer (score 1):

Solution special for you (it's not mine): [Simple IP Access List for Play 2 with Java](http://feadro.com/simple-ip-access-list-for-play-2-1-with-java/)

It based on the annotations (as biesior propose) and it is already ready to use. You need just copy two files in to your project and then you can configure IP list in the applications.conf like this

```
restricttohostgroup {
    groups {
        default = ["0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1", "127.0.0.1", "10.0.0.", "192.168.0."],
        admin = ["192.168.7."]
    },
    redirect = "http://github.com"
}
```

Comment: I completely forgot to mention that I'm using 2.3.x and Scala, but code you referenced is pretty simple to understand and apply in some other way. Thank you